# Custom MKAnnotation

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation

I have annotation with image on the left, title, desc, and button on right, and now I want to create annotation as below, how can I do this? I will appreciate any help

http://postimage.org/image/4s61pnwcf/

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly the problem is if you really have custom complex annotation already?

Comment: I dont know how to add this line and third text after line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard callouts are fixed to: an image to the left, title, subtitle, and a button on the right. If you want to do anything more sophisticated you have to provide your own view from scratch.

You can help yourself with [MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView](https://github.com/grgcombs/MultiRowCalloutAnnotationView) This library assumes that you will provide it with a table, but you could just provide it with one cell that contains your whole view. The advantage of using it is that it will draw the nice semi-transparent background of a callout for you.

Comment: Looks complicated for me

Comment: It is. You cannot get everything for free even in a brilliantly designed sdk

Comment: Nothing is impossible :)